# Calibrate monitors having the same EDID

Tags: xrandr, color-management, icc, monitor-calibration

I need to calibrate two external monitors (they are not really monitors, they are 2 BlackMagic Teranex Mini HDMI to SDI 12G, but they are considered as monitors by Ubuntu) having the same EDID.

Here's the output of `xrandr --props` :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 11520 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 710mm x 400mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0009a4000000000000
        1b1901038047289612daffa3584aa229
        17494b20000001010101010101010101
        010101010101011d8018711c1620582c
        2500c48e2100009e011d007251d01e20
        6e285500c48e2100001e000000fc0054
        4552414e45582d4d2d554844000000fd
        00323c0f2d08000a2020202020200113
        02034375558584866194939560a05f5e
        5d6263a1a29f90031201230f070483ff
        000072030c001000003c20c084010203
        04014101db67d85dc401788007e50f88
        0010008c0aa01451f01600267c430013
        8e21000098011d80d0721c1620102c25
        80c48e2100009e011d00bc52d01e20b8
        285540c48e2100001e00000000000093
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
   4096x2160     25.00 +  24.00    23.98  
   3840x2160     59.94*   50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1920x1080     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  

HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+7680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 710mm x 400mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0009a4000000000000
        1b1901038047289612daffa3584aa229
        17494b20000001010101010101010101
        010101010101011d8018711c1620582c
        2500c48e2100009e011d007251d01e20
        6e285500c48e2100001e000000fc0054
        4552414e45582d4d2d554844000000fd
        00323c0f2d08000a2020202020200113
        02034375558584866194939560a05f5e
        5d6263a1a29f90031201230f070483ff
        000072030c001000003c20c084010203
        04014101db67d85dc401788007e50f88
        0010008c0aa01451f01600267c430013
        8e21000098011d80d0721c1620102c25
        80c48e2100009e011d00bc52d01e20b8
        285540c48e2100001e00000000000093
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: HDMI 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
   1920x1080     60.05 +  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.00    50.04  
   4096x2160     25.00    24.00    23.98  
   3840x2160     59.94*   50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1440x480      60.05  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  

eDP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004d10461400000000
        22190104a52615780edf50a35435b526
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101014dd000a0f0703e803020
        35007ed710000018a4a600a0f0703e80
        3020350081d710000018000000fe0043
        4b375437814c51313733443100000000
        0002410328001200000b010a20200074
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   3840x2160     60.00*+  48.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05
```

As you can see, HDMI-0 and DP-0 have the same EDID. eDP-1-1 is my laptop's screen.

Here's now the output of `colormgr get-devices` :

```
Chemin d'objet:/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Blackmagic_Design_TERANEX_M_UHD_tim_1000
Propriétaire: tim
Créé:        décembre 12 2019, 04:25:22 
Modifié:      décembre 12 2019, 04:25:45 
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Modèle:       TERANEX-M-UHD
Vendeur:       Blackmagic Design
Numéro de série:unknown
Seat:          seat0
Portée:       temp
Espace de couleur:rgb
ID de périphérique:xrandr-Blackmagic Design-TERANEX-M-UHD
Profil 1:      icc-611672fba65e299c30aecf3271dde245
               /home/tim/.local/share/icc/BlackMagic Teranex Mini HDMI to SDI 12G.icc
Métadonnées: XRANDR_name=DP-0
Métadonnées: OutputPriority=primary
Métadonnées: OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon 
Métadonnées: OutputEdidMd5=5fa57e0cc37f9c4948de5bfbc6d14a2e

Chemin d'objet:/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Sharp_Corporation_tim_1000
Propriétaire: tim
Créé:        décembre 12 2019, 04:25:22 
Modifié:      décembre 12 2019, 04:25:22 
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      Yes
Modèle:       Precision 7730
Vendeur:       Dell
Numéro de série:unknown
Seat:          seat0
Portée:       temp
Espace de couleur:rgb
ID de périphérique:xrandr-Sharp Corporation
Profil 1:      icc-947873912bb2dde2cfd996c79b3295f0
               /home/tim/.local/share/icc/Ecran Precision 7730.icc
Métadonnées: XRANDR_name=eDP-1-1
Métadonnées: OutputPriority=secondary
Métadonnées: OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon 
Métadonnées: OutputEdidMd5=e7b85d050804164dc63a0ecc5d72f4f3
```

Colord only sees one of the two Teranex Mini. As a result, the "Color" settings panel of Ubuntu settings app only lists one of the two Teranex Mini, and I cannot set an ICC profile to the second one.

Is there anything I can do? Would playing with my xorg.conf solve the problem?

EDIT: I tried to edit the EDID and flash it to the device with edid-rw (https://github.com/bulletmark/edid-rw), it didn't work. I guess that the device's memory is not writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I workarounded the problem but uploading a 3D LUT on the Teranex Mini SDI to HDMI that I'm using to plug my HDMI monitor. This does not solves the EDID problem but at least I can get correct colors.

It might interest others to know that the AJA HA5-12G should correctly support the EDID, as it is explicitely written on the product page (https://www.aja.com/products/ha5-12g). Might still be a good idea to ask the support if the EDID is different on each device before buying though.